# Fragment 's onCreate() show incorrect index values by getArguments()

Tags: android, fragment

i am using Fragments and has 10 activities. I saved to each bundle inside newInstance(). But i am getting incorrect or next index values in onCreate(). I am able to swipe left and right. but onCreate() displaying me next index value.

my code:-

```
public static final ScorecardFragment newInstance(ScorecardHoles scorecardHoles, Context cnt) {

   context = cnt;

   holeNum = scorecardHoles.getHole();
   ScorecardFragment f = new ScorecardFragment();

    System.out.println("hole number in newInstance():-"+holeNum);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("holeNum", holeNum);
    f.setArguments(bundle);
    return f;
}

  @Override
public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
   holeNum = bundle.getInt("holeNum", 0);
   System.out.println("hole number in onResume():-"+holeNum);
```

}

my previous class which is calling to Fragment.

```
    private void Initialize() {

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager1);

    pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter); 
    //mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
//  mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ScorecardFragment()); 
    pageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

private List<Fragment> getFragments(ArrayList<ScorecardCourseDetails> list) {
     fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        for(int i=0; i<18 ; i++) 
        {
         ScorecardFragment f1 = ScorecardFragment.newInstance(list.get(0).getScorecardHolesList().get(i), this);
         fList.add(f1);
        }
    return fList;
```

}

other code:-

```
public class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private List<Fragment> fragments;

public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}
```

}

my Log:-

```
03-25 19:48:20.135: I/System.out(12554): hole number in newInstance():-1
03-25 19:48:20.135: I/System.out(12554): hole number in newInstance():-2
03-25 19:48:20.135: I/System.out(12554): hole number in newInstance():-3
03-25 19:48:20.135: I/System.out(12554): hole number in newInstance():-4
03-25 19:48:20.135: I/System.out(12554): hole number in newInstance():-5
03-25 19:48:20.136: I/System.out(12554): hole number in newInstance():-6
03-25 19:48:20.136: I/System.out(12554): hole number in newInstance():-7
03-25 19:48:20.136: I/System.out(12554): hole number in newInstance():-8
03-25 19:48:20.136: I/System.out(12554): hole number in newInstance():-9
03-25 19:48:20.136: I/System.out(12554): hole number in newInstance():-10
03-25 19:48:20.136: I/System.out(12554): hole number in newInstance():-11
03-25 19:48:20.136: I/System.out(12554): hole number in newInstance():-12
03-25 19:48:20.136: I/System.out(12554): hole number in newInstance():-13
03-25 19:48:20.136: I/System.out(12554): hole number in newInstance():-14
03-25 19:48:20.136: I/System.out(12554): hole number in newInstance():-15
03-25 19:48:20.136: I/System.out(12554): hole number in newInstance():-16
03-25 19:48:20.136: I/System.out(12554): hole number in newInstance():-17
03-25 19:48:20.137: I/System.out(12554): hole number in newInstance():-18
03-25 19:48:20.191: I/System.out(12554): hole number in onResume():-1
03-25 19:48:20.191: I/System.out(12554): hole number in onResume():-2
```

Comment: Post the code you are using.

Comment: @blackbelt please check

Comment: you can remove the context parameter, and use getActivity in its place . Still the issue is not related to the code you posted.

Comment: my log:-  once fragment is loaded completly. onResume is called Two times once. and after that calling one times when using swip

Comment: public static final myclass new Instance( mygetsetclass obj) ... what's this?

Answer (score 0):

```
  fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        for(int i=0; i<18 ; i++) 
        {
         ScorecardFragment f1 = ScorecardFragment.newInstance(list.get(0).getScorecardHolesList().get(i), this);
         fList.add(f1);
        }
```

it should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
   ScorecardCourseDetails scorecardCourseDetails = list.get(i);
   for (int j = 0; j < scorecardCourseDetails.getScorecardHolesList().size(); j++) {
         ScorecardFragment f1 = ScorecardFragment.newInstance(scorecardCourseDetails.getScorecardHolesList().get(j), this);
         fList.add(f1);
   }

}
```

Comment: not working, i got null exception at fList. i solved but still getting next index values in onResume() . I am using also onCreateView() and getting correct values for each, but onResume() not

Comment: you need to create fList as you did before

Comment: but it does work. Can not understand why you expect something different

Comment: you will see that calling onResume() two time when fragment loaded

Comment: but you are using a ViewPager, it is the normal/expected behaviour

Comment: try calling mViewPager. setOffscreenPageLimit(0) and check if it makes difference

Comment: i did. but did not get any effect.v:(

Comment: @blackbeit   i noted my Fragment onResume is calling two times. i also check by phone light off and on. may we do something for calling only one time to onResume() ?

Comment: that's the correct behaviour of ViewPager. It does implement a lazy-loading mechanism

Comment: is onResume() called twice in Fragment activity?

Comment: I am using SlidingMenu-library

Comment: no sorry, I thought was the Fragment's one. Then I am clueless

Comment: please not say to sorry, you are the only person who helping me. thank you